# Documentation for the meaning of entries in /proc/meminfo and /proc/vmstat

Tags: proc, documentation

Where can I find documentation explaining the meaning of entries in `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/vmstat` files? I looked up on the web and the man page of `proc` but could not find much. Many entries are self explanatory but some are not.

Preferably, looking for documentation that indicates how to interpret the various values in those entries and what it means for instance if some values are too high or too low.

Comment: You may want to look into systat code. It documents a lot of /proc resources, though it not as exhaustive as you may want https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/rd_stats.c#L242

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/proc/meminfo`:

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-proc-meminfo-file-analyzing-memory-utilization-in-linux/

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#meminfo

`/proc/vmstat`:

There's very little documentation available for it:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html

And if you can read C:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/vmstat.c